# In wordpress generated Fxc393QU.html file

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress site suddenly generated unknown file which name is `Fxc393QU.html` in that file only content `Fxc393QU`. I'm sure this is generated by any script.

I dont know how this happen but due to this query string URL no longer work.

One more thing is this file **owner** and **group** is `root root`

nobody create file without `sudo` command.

Is my worpdress site hacked ?

Comment: Yes, it is quite possible that it has been hacked. See the [WordPress FAQ](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) on that topic.

Comment: I have update question can you please in to that. If you know the solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please scan your site using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/